# How setup laravel-notification-channels/webpush

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-notification

I have installed https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/webpush
in my project but when send notifications there are nothing. It doesnt work
This is laravel notifications documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications

This is my code - I have created a notification:

```
class AccountApproved extends Notification {
use Queueable;

public function __construct()
{
    //
}

public function via($notifiable)
{
    return [WebPushChannel::class];
}

public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'title' => 'Hello from Laravel!',
        'body' => 'Thank you for using our application.',
        'action_url' => 'https://laravel.com',
        'created' => Carbon::now()->toIso8601String()
    ];
}

public function toWebPush($notifiable, $notification)
{
    return WebPushMessage::create()
        ->title('Hello from Laravel!')
        ->icon('/notification-icon.png')
        ->body('Thank you for using our application.')
        ->action('View app', 'view_app');
}}
```

and I call Notification in my controller:

```
     $when = Carbon::now();

    $request->user()->notify((new AccountApproved)->delay($when));
```

But I Webpush doesnt work. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are running queue worker like this:

```
php artisan queue:work
```

in command line. Otherwise queued notification won't be sent.

In case it doesn't help look at your error log and verify if there are any errors in there

Comment: it's weird, php artisan queue:work can't work. After several minutes of waiting, the console is still frozen. I'll get the solution on Google and I come back

Comment: Maybe it works but sending notifications fails and you are getting errors in your `laravel.log` file

Answer (score 0):

For the method `delay()` to work you must add to your Notification `implements ShouldQueue`

```
class AccountApproved extends Notification implements ShouldQueue { ... }
```

and ofc `use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;` before your class